# Auto Mount Hard Drives

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I have Linux on my system and have used the DISKS GUI to auto Boot my HDD and all works well, that is until I attempt to write to the HDD or remove files and even make a new directory.
If I open as ROOT I can then do everything ok.
This is in the DISKS options part "nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=500GB"
My question is this - is there a way to modify this line to perform a mount that gives me FULL access to this drive after boot?

Comment: What format is partition? Often Disks default parameters are not what you should use. Is drive HDD (include relatime) or SSD(include noatime)? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting/1013700#1013700 I just use relatime for my data partition that is ext4.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to read/write anywhere in the file system, you need to be granted permission or you need to be owner. The easiest way to obtain user permissions on an entire connected partition is to change the owner of the mount point of the partition, as:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER <mountpoint>
```

You can type `$USER` as is if you are granting permission to yourself: `$USER` is automatically replaced by the current user that issues the command.

Replace  by the full pathname of the flder where the partition is mounted. You can see this folder as the second entry in the line of your drive, in the output of the command `mount` or in the output of the command `lsblk`.